# Weird if elseif logic in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logic

I have a page that displays certain HTML based on the query string that is loaded in the URL.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
<?php 
    // grab querystring section
    $w = getQuerys('section');

    if ($w == "main") {?>
```

DISPLAY HTML VERSION ONE

```
<? } else if ($w == 'types')  {?>
```

DISPLAY HTML VERSION TWO

```
<?php }  ?>
```

For some reason, this logic works fine on my Web hosting site, but not on my workstation using XAMPP. When I run this on my workstation, both HTML VERSION ONE AND TOW are displayed at the same time on the page.

I'm afraid I'm at a bit of a loss for this. I've confirmed that the getQuerys function works fine by echoing out the $w variable.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

Comment: If you do a "view source" in you xampp, does it show the PHP code as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing php shorts tags with long tags. I expect XAMPP doesn't have short tags enabled, so change the following line:

```
<?php } else if ($w == 'types')  {?>
```

Comment: Ok. That was to easy. Thanks for your help. I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks again.

Comment: It was easy only because I had the same problem not that long ago. You can enable php short tags in the php.ini file by the way, if you existing php code uses short tags.